# Editing RTF files on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf, nsattributedstring

So, with the Text Kit additions to iOS7, it's very easy -- three lines of code -- to make an NSAttributedString from an RTF file. It works great, and even RTFD files work. However, in searching Apple's docs, there doesn't seem to be any roundtrip capability. I.E. They don't provide a way to save an NSAttributedString back to an RTF.

Does anyone know of an open source solution that would enable that capability in iOS7? I know there's at least one app (Textilus) that does this, but I need to incorporate that capability into my own apps. I've reviewed past questions on here, and done a general search of the web, but the only thing I have found are links to a github project that gives a 404 now. I would really like to be able to make an RTF editor,and the only missing piece is saving to RTF. I thought I would ask on here before I resort to building it myself.

Comment: Am I missing something, or can't you just `NSData *rtfData = [myAttributedString dataFromRange: NSMakeRange(0, [myAttributedString length]) documentAttributes: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType} error: nil];` then write the `rtfData` to a file?

Comment: Ahh! Yes! That works. Thanks. Post it as the answer if you want me to mark it as the solution.